# Secure video links with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, video

We currently host online tutorials on our website embeding the videos using Youtube.

However I have been asked to secure the video links so users need to authenticate in order to view the videos, and once authenticated, not be able to copy the video link and share it with others as they will be paid tutorials.

We use AWS to store our other assets (Website images, documents, etc) and want to use AWS to now store our videos.

Does anyone know the best way to secure these links so they can only be used from within our website and not be able to share the video links?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more about [IT security](https://security.stackexchange.com) than programming.

Answer (score 1):

First of all think how much effort you want to put into solving a problem, that the world failed to solved in the last 40 years. We had VHS and everyone could copy everything. We had CDs and DVDs with copy protection. BlueRays can and are ripped too. If you consider how a book can be copied then it is a problem we failed to solve in the last 2000+ years.

Have you played with [youtube-dl](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/)? Have you seen how easy it is to download things from youtube once you get access to it? And I could always use a screen recorder tool to capture the screen if all else fails.

Given how easy it is to bypass the copy protection, how much time do you want to spend into solving the impossible? Do you want to make the code more complex and the architecture more crappy (and the usability worse) along the way?

If the history has shown anything is that legal measures are the only way to protect from piracy. So you have two options here: pretend you do something to protect knowing you will fail or talk to the managers and convince them, that there are better ways of spending money.

Comment: I agree with you totally Marek, I have lost count the amount of times I have drilled this very same argument into them.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all objects in the bucket are private.

`A pre-signed` URL may solve your current problem.
Have a look on below links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html
https://www.msp360.com/resources/blog/s3-pre-signed-url-guide/

Comment: Sorry but this does not solves the problem of being able to access the video after due authentication . Anyone with the presigned url will be able to access the video...